# Check overlaping timeslots for laravel query

Tags: mysql, laravel

While booking a time-slot I want to check if that slot is overlapping with any other already booked time-slot. Used following query for same which is not correct:

```
Availability::where('date',date('Y-m-d',strtotime($request->available_date)))
             ->where(function ($query) use($request){
                  $query->whereBetween('start_time', [date("H:i:s", strtotime($request->start_time)), date("H:i:s", strtotime($request->end_time))])
                        ->orWhereBetween('end_time', [date("H:i:s", strtotime($request->start_time)), date("H:i:s", strtotime($request->end_time))]);
              })
              ->get();
```

Thanks In advance!

Comment: You can try like: `$Availability = Availability::where
(
    function( $query ) use( $request)
    {
        $query->where( 'start_time', '<', $request->end_time )
              ->where( 'end_time', '>', $request->start_time); 
    }
)->count();`

Comment: Its's not working!

Comment: Try: `$startTime = $request->start_time; $endTime = $request->end_time; $Availability = Availability::where(function ($query) use ($startTime, $endTime) {
 $query->where(function ($query) use ($startTime, $endTime) {
    $query->where('start_time', '>=', $startTime)
            ->where('end_time', '<', $startTime);
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($startTime, $endTime) {
        $query->where('start_time', '<', $endTime)
                ->where('end_time', '>=', $endTime);
    });
})->count();`

Comment: Thanks, only following line need to altered and its works fine:

$query->where('start_time', '>=', $startTime) ->where('end_time', '<', $startTime); })

to-->>>

$query->where('start_time', '<=', $startTime) ->where('end_time', '>', $startTime); })

Comment: Glad i could help you! I've posted my answer, please accept and upvote it! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, to be able to have access to `$startTime` and `$endTime` within the query closure you will need to pass them through using the `use` construct i.e.

```
function ($query) use ($startTime, $endTime)
```

Try like below:

```
$startTime = $request->start_time; 
$endTime = $request->end_time; 

$Availability = Availability::where(function ($query) use ($startTime, $endTime) { 
    $query
    ->where(function ($query) use ($startTime, $endTime) {
        $query
            ->where('start_time', '<=', $startTime)
            ->where('end_time', '>', $startTime);
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($startTime, $endTime) {
        $query
            ->where('start_time', '<', $endTime)
            ->where('end_time', '>=', $endTime);
    });
})->count();
```

Hope this will helps you!

Comment: Event A overlaps Event B if Event A starts before Event B ends, and ends after Event B starts. So that's the only comparison needed.

Answer (score 0):

**Little Modified Query** Hope it will work for all the people searching time slot booking algorithm.

```
$Availability=  Availability::
                    where(function ($query) use ($start_time, $end_time) { 
                        $query
                           ->whereBetween('start_time', [$start_time, $end_time])
                           ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($start_time, $end_time) {
                                    $query
                                        ->whereBetween('end_time', [$start_time, $end_time]);
                                });
                     })->count();
```